# MongoCursorTimeoutException for aggregate function

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to fetch some data from the Mongo collection using aggregate function, but it is giving me MongoCursorTimeoutException. I am trying to select only fifty records at a time and the collection has over 17M records. This is done from PHP and my code is as follows :

```
$data = $my_collection->aggregate(array(
                                   array('$match'=>$filter_query),
                                   array('$group'=>array('_id'=>'$email')), 
                                   array('$skip'=>$offset),    
                                   array('$limit'=>$per_page)
                                 ));
```

and the $filter_query is another array which contains the timestmap and it is like

```
Array
(
    [timestamp] => Array
        (
            [$gt] => 1383890400
            [$lt] => 1384495200
        )

)
```

I am not sure why this is happening as I am trying to fetch only 50 records. I think the agrression is performed after selecting all the records and it is causing the error. Any better method to do this other than aggression ?

I can set the timeout to -1, but is it a good option as the driver will wait forever to get the initial response ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set timeout option for aggregate function you should use `command` function of MongoDB object instance. For example:

```
$result = $database->command(
array(
    'aggregate' => $my_collection,
    'pipeline' => array(
        array('$match' => $filter_query),
        array('$group' => array('_id'=>'$email')),
                    array('$skip'=>$offset),
        array('$limit'=>$per_page)
    )
),
array( 'timeout' => $timeout )
);
```

For more information please refer to [documentation](http://php.net/manual/ru/mongodb.command.php)

Comment: As a part of optimization you may
1) first of all select only 15 emails;
2) then select records referred to selected email;
3) apply all other rules.

This way you'll significantly reduce number of records to aggregate.

Also it'll be great if you could use cache or precalculated results for such expensive operations.

Comment: by the way it is returning an error for me [errmsg] => exception: wrong type for field (aggregate) 3 != 2

Comment: You may refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131833/mongodb-aggregate-query-using-php-driver) on stackoverflow

Comment: As of driver version 1.5.0 it looks like you can pass in an array of options where you can define the timeout with the maxTimeMS parameter. 

For example:
$data = $my_collection->aggregate( $pipeline, ['maxTimeMS' => 120000] );

See http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.aggregate.php

Comment: `timeout` option is deprecated. It must be `['socketTimeoutMS' => $timeout]`.