# Invalid Input Resource Mongodb Command PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to get around the 30 second cursor time limit and avoid a MongoCursorTimeoutException by using DB->command method as seen here: [MongoCursorTimeoutException for aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19996692/mongocursortimeoutexception-for-aggregate-function)

When I try to aggregate, command instantly returns:
`array(3) { ["ok"]=> float(0) ["errmsg"]=> string(42) "Invalid input resource, " ["code"]=> int(17138) }` There is pretty much no documentation on this and the only think I could find is the source code where the error takes place https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/master/src/mongo/db/pipeline/pipeline.cpp#L327

Can someone please help? The pipeline works fine if I run `collection->aggregate(pipeline, options)` so I don't think it is the pipeline. My code is below:

```
$connection = new MongoClient( 'mongodb://user:pass@mydb.biz' );
$summaryDB = $connection->selectDB('Summary');
$summaryCollection = $summaryDB->selectCollection('hitSummary');
//agg pipeline
        $pipeline = 
        [
            [
                '$match' => [
                    'date' => [
                        '$gte' => $weekAgo,
                        '$lt' => $today,
                    ]
                ]
            ], [
                '$group' => [
                    '_id' => [
                        'client' => '$client',
                        'date' => '$date',
                    ],
                    //conversions
                    'z1is' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.import.z1.count' ],
                    'z2is' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.import.z2.count' ],
                    'z3is' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.import.z3.count' ],
                    'z1ps' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.pixel.z1.count' ],
                    'z2ps' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.pixel.z2.count' ],
                    'z3ps' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.pixel.z3.count' ],
                    'z1as' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.apiOnly.z1.count' ],
                    'z2as' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.apiOnly.z2.count' ],
                    'z3as' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.apiOnly.z3.count' ],
                    'z1ss' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.s2s.z1.count' ],
                    'z2ss' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.s2s.z2.count' ],
                    'z3ss' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.sales.s2s.z3.count' ],
                    //clicks
                    'z1ic' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.import.z1.count' ],
                    'z2ic' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.import.z2.count' ],
                    'z3ic' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.import.z3.count' ],
                    'z1pc' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.pixel.z1.count' ],
                    'z2pc' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.pixel.z2.count' ],
                    'z3pc' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.pixel.z3.count' ],
                    'z1ac' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.apiOnly.z1.count' ],
                    'z2ac' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.apiOnly.z2.count' ],
                    'z3ac' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.apiOnly.z3.count' ],
                    'z1sc' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.s2s.z1.count' ],
                    'z2sc' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.s2s.z2.count' ],
                    'z3sc' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.click.s2s.z3.count' ],
                    //impressions
                    'z1ii' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.import.z1.count' ],
                    'z2ii' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.import.z2.count' ],
                    'z3ii' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.import.z3.count' ],
                    'z1pi' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.pixel.z1.count' ],
                    'z2pi' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.pixel.z2.count' ],
                    'z3pi' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.pixel.z3.count' ],
                    'z1ai' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.apiOnly.z1.count' ],
                    'z2ai' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.apiOnly.z2.count' ],
                    'z3ai' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.apiOnly.z3.count' ],
                    'z1si' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.s2s.z1.count' ],
                    'z2si' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.s2s.z2.count' ],
                    'z3si' => [ '$sum' => '$actions.display.s2s.z3.count' ],
                ]
            ], [
                '$project' => [
                    'impressions' => [ '$add' => ['$z1ii', '$z2ii', '$z3ii',
                                                  '$z1pi', '$z2pi', '$z3pi',
                                                  '$z1ai', '$z2ai', '$z3ai',
                                                  '$z1si', '$z2si', '$z3si'] ],
                    'clicks' => [      '$add' => ['$z1ic', '$z2ic', '$z3ic',
                                                  '$z1pc', '$z2pc', '$z3pc',
                                                  '$z1ac', '$z2ac', '$z3ac',
                                                  '$z1sc', '$z2sc', '$z3sc'] ],
                    'importSales' => [ '$add' => ['$z1is', '$z2is', '$z3is'] ],
                     'pixelSales' => [ '$add' => ['$z1ps', '$z2ps', '$z3ps'] ],
                       'apiSales' => [ '$add' => ['$z1as', '$z2as', '$z3as'] ],
                       's2sSales' => [ '$add' => ['$z1ss', '$z2ss', '$z3ss'] ],
                ]
            ]
        ];

        //do something with this
        $options = [ 'timeout' => -1 ];

        $result = $summaryDB->command(
            [
                'aggregate' => $summaryCollection,
                'pipeline' => $pipeline,
            ],
            $options
        );


        var_dump($result);
```

Comment: What is $summaryCollection?  It's expected to be the namespace string and not object that's the DB/collection - "hitSummary" in your case.

Comment: fixed the timeout by passing ['connectTimeoutMS' => 86400000, 'socketTimeoutMS' => 86400000] to the MongoConnect command like this:
`$connection = new MongoClient( 'mongodb://user:pass@mysite.biz:27018/admin', ['connectTimeoutMS' => 86400000, 'socketTimeoutMS' => 86400000] );`

Comment: see my answer - there was a simpler issue to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run DB command, the first argument is the name of the command as the key and the value is the name of the collection.

In your case you should be passing "hitSummary" as the value of 'aggregate' and not the collection object.

See simple command example here: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.command.php