# mongodb sort aggregate in php

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a database in MongoDB `users`. It contains following fields:

- _id
- fname
- lname

I tried to concatenate the first name (fname) and last name (lname) through aggregate function with the following php code.

```
$cursor = $this->users->aggregate(
  array(
    '$project' => array(
      'name' => array('$concat' => array('$fname', ' ', '$lname'))
    )
  )
);
```

This seems to work fine.
But How do we sort the results?
I tried to use this line of code to sort the result

```
$cursor->sort(array("name" => 1));
```

But this give me the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function sort() on array
```

However, I tried to use this code in console and it worked fine:

```
db.users.aggregate({
  $project: {
    'name' {$concat: ['$fname', ' ', '$lname']}
  }
}, {$sort: {name: 1}});
```

This code worked nicely and I get the result in sorted manner.

What might be the problem with sort function in php code?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may add sort in the same array, please refer [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131833/mongodb-aggregate-query-using-php-driver)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
$cursor = $this->users->aggregate(
  array(
    '$project' => array(
      'name' => array('$concat' => array('$fname', ' ', '$lname'))
    )
  ),array(
    '$sort' => array(
       'name' => 1
    )
  )
);
```

Hope this help.