# PHP - Aggregation $project $cond if/then syntax MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I have PHP script that have Mongo query inside, in Mongo Booster this query works normal, but when i try to implement in PHP i get

> "Warning: Illegal offset type in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpMongo\index.php on
>   line 14"

Can someone help me to debug and fix script?

This is my PHP script with query on MongoDB

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new MongoDB\Client;

$companydb = $client->bol_rac;

$empcollection = $companydb->bol_rac;

$documentlist = $empcollection->aggregate(
    [
        [
         '$project'[
               [
                 'id'=>[1],
                 'id_drzavljanstvo'=>[1],
                 'location'=>
                  [
                    '$cond'=> [ [ '$eg'=> [ "id_drzavljanstvo", 688 ] ],'Country', 'Foreign country' ]
                  ]
               ]
           ]
        ]

    ]);

foreach($documentlist as $doc){

    var_dump($doc);
}
```

When i remove quotes on variables, then i get error that variables is not defined.

Comment: change  `'$project' => [` instead of `'$project'[`

Comment: @SuneelKumar i tried that already and again i get the same error

Comment: Try this `'project' => [`

Comment: @SuneelKumar again same error, i tried also on all variables to do that, again same, i tried all combination of that

Comment: simply remove `''` colons check reference here https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/

Comment: @SuneelKumar sorry, my mistake, i tried to do previous like on manual, but than it gives me error that my variables are not defined, when i do as first your comment '$project' =>[ it removes eror, but than i have this error Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\RuntimeException: $project specification must be an object

Comment: See this for the correct syntax: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131833/mongodb-aggregate-query-using-php-driver