# group by email address is not working with mongodb in php

Tags: mongodb

I want to do group by with email_address field in mongodb in php, here is my code for this but it is not working, can anyone please look into that and give me proper solution for that ?

```
$m = new MongoDB\Client("mongodb://localhost:27017");
$db = $m->mailchimp;   
$collection = $db->users;
$aggregate[] = [
    '$group' => [
        '_id' => 'email_address',  
        'email_address' => array('$sum'=>'1'),
    ],
];
$data=$collection->aggregate($aggregate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing `$` in query.

```
'_id' => '$email_address',
'$email_address' => array('$sum'=>'1')
```

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116396/8612835)

[PHP Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14131875/8612835)

Comment: It gives me this error now : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\CommandException: The field name '$email_address' cannot be an operator name in /var/www/html/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Aggregate.php:263

Comment: @NikulPanchal I don't know much in php systax.

Comment: @NikulPanchal I have add another php link it mey help you in syntax. :)