# MongoDB sort with conditions

Tags: php, mysql, database, mongodb, sorting

I have collection like this:

```
{ 
    "_id" : 13965 ,
    "name" : "p 1",
    "sort_order" : 0,
    "quantity" : 5 
}
{ 
    "_id" : 8000 ,
    "name" : "p 4",
    "sort_order" : 500,
    "quantity" : -10
}
{ 
    "_id" : 13980 ,
    "name" : "p 2",
    "sort_order" : 50,
    "quantity" : 2
}
{ 
    "_id" : 9753 ,
    "name" : "p 5",
    "sort_order" : 0,
    "quantity" : 0
}
{ 
    "_id" : 2000 ,
    "name" : "p 3",
    "sort_order" : 6,
    "quantity" : 1
}
{ 
    "_id" : 65230,
    "name" : "p 6",
    "sort_order" : 20,
    "quantity" : 0
}
```

after sort, i want it to look like this :

```
{ 
    "_id" : 13980 ,
    "name" : "p 2",
    "sort_order" : 50,
    "quantity" : 2
}

{ 
    "_id" : 2000 ,
    "name" : "p 3",
    "sort_order" : 6,
    "quantity" : 1
}

{ 
    "_id" : 13965 ,
    "name" : "p 1",
    "sort_order" : 0,
    "quantity" : 5 
}

{ 
    "_id" : 8000 ,
    "name" : "p 4",
    "sort_order" : 500,
    "quantity" : -10
}

{ 
    "_id" : 65230,
    "name" : "p 6",
    "sort_order" : 20,
    "quantity" : 0
}

{ 
    "_id" : 9753 ,
    "name" : "p 5",
    "sort_order" : 0,
    "quantity" : 0
}
```

I want all the cases that `quantity` has zero or below zero to be at the end of the list and the rest to sort by `sort_order`. This Mysql query work:

SELECT product_id,quantity,sort_order FROM product ORDER by quantity <=0 ASC , sort_order DESC

but i need in `mongoDB` :))

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this question tagged with PHP, but does not contain any PHP code?

Comment: @NicoHaase , I want the answer with php code.

Comment: Then please share your attempts to resolve the problems

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      sortQuantity: { $cond: [ { $lte: ["$quantity", 0 ] }, 0, 1 ] }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      sortQuantity: 1,
      sort_order: -1
    }
  },
  { $unset: "sortQuantity" }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/aLS7hwMQWeI)

Comment: thanks a lot. Can you give me PHP code too?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131833/mongodb-aggregate-query-using-php-driver the transformation is quite obvious. You can also pass the entire JSON string to [toPHP](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mongodb.bson-tophp.php) and [fromJSON](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mongodb.bson-fromjson.php) like `toPHP(fromJSON( '[{$addFields ...]' ))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- `$facet` to categorize incoming data into `quantity>0` and `quantity <=0`
- `$sort` to sort as you expected
- `$concatArray` to concat both array into one array
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array
- `$replaceRoot` to make the deconstructed variable as root

here is the ocde

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$facet": {
      "lteZero": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $lte: [ "$quantity", 0 ]
            }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { sort_order: -1, quantity: 1 } }
      ],
      "gtZero": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $gt: [ "$quantity", 0 ]
            }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { sort_order: -1, quantity: 1 } }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      combined: {
        "$concatArrays": [ "$gtZero", "$lteZero" ]
      }
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$combined" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$combined" } }
])
```

**working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5KYOYbfyriw)**

Comment: Maybe an overkill for a simple sort.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes, may be, but this is his expected output, thats why i used this way

Answer (score 0):

It is simple and easy, you may use a cursor.sort() function to order the collection:

db.collection.find().sort( { quantity: -1 } )

These examples return all documents in the collection named collection sorted by the quantity field in descending order. Specify a value to $orderby of negative one (e.g. -1, as above) to sort in descending order or a positive value (e.g. 1) to sort in ascending order.

For more information please visit:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/