# PHP Mongo Find in array

Tags: php, mongodb

Good morning!
I have mongodb base:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("........."),
    "0" : {
        "title" : "name",
        "description" : "database"
    },
    "1" : {
        "title" : "name2",
        "description" : "database"
    },
    "2" : {
        "title" : "name3",
        "description" : "database"
    },
    "3" : {
        "title" : "name4",
        "description" : "database"
    },
    "4" : {
        "title" : "name5",
        "description" : "database"
    },
...
```

How do I search by name with regex?

I've tried, but I'm probably  search not inside the array, right?

```
db.test.find({"title": /.*n.*/})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. change object to key-value aray
2. filter the array with regex
3. if array is not empty then the doc is what you need

you can check the result in the mongoplayground link below

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $ne: [
          {
            $filter: {
              input: {
                $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
              },
              as: "r",
              cond: {
                $regexMatch: {
                  input: "$$r.v.title",
                  regex: "name2"
                }
              }
            }
          },
          []
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gDTtG41xVD7)

Comment: Thanks, YuTing! 
1) There are no other options?
2) I use php, is this the only option? And maybe tell me how to do it in php?

Comment: 1. I cannot come with other options. 2. convert to [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14131833/mongodb-aggregate-query-using-php-driver) on your own

Comment: I accepted you answer. Can you please tell me, to use mongodb for 50 million records and search them with .*, is it a good idea or better not to do that? Or is it bad for nosql?

Comment: @Alex It depends on how long is your query take. If it takes minutes then it's a bad idea. If it takes seconds then it's maybe acceptable.